# Произведение двузначных чисел в массиве

Tags: c, алгоритм

Требуется написать программу, выводящую произведение двузначных чисел в массиве, которые не кратны семи. Я написал на С следующее

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
void main(void)
{
    long A[N];
    long j, i, p;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%ld", &A[i]);
    }
    p = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (A[i] >= 10 && A[i] <= 99 && A[i] % 7 != 0) {
            j = A[i];
            p = p * j;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld", p);
}
```

Но это выводит только последний элемент массива. Помогите поймать ошибку.

Comment: Вставь код прямо сюда, некоторым лениво ходить по ссылке.

Comment: Зачем вы исправили код на правильный?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вместо <= 10, должно быть >= 10.
Во-вторых, вместо побитового оператора &, надо использовать логический оператор &&. В данном случае это не влияет на результат, но в других случаях могут возникнуть проблемы.